# ValueError: ('Unrecognized keyword arguments:', dict_keys(['ragged']))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I trained a cell segmentation model on google colab, one with tensorflow version 1.x, and the other on 2.x. I downloaded this model and am now trying to load it and predict a preselected image I downloaded. Training and building the model, I used tf.keras.layers.layername  Code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
from tensorflow.python.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform


def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 100
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

#def load_model():
with CustomObjectScope({'GlorotUniform':glorot_uniform()}):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./models/nuclei_1-15.h5", compile=False)

def predict():
    prediction = model.predict([prepare("./images/cell.jpeg")])
    print(prediction)

predict()
```

with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_werk.py", line 20, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./models/nuclei_1-15.h5", compile=False)
  File "/home/hmrbcnt/Documents/thesis/try_2.1.5/trial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/models.py", line 246, in load_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/hmrbcnt/Documents/thesis/try_2.1.5/trial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/models.py", line 324, in model_from_config
    return layer_module.deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/hmrbcnt/Documents/thesis/try_2.1.5/trial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 63, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/hmrbcnt/Documents/thesis/try_2.1.5/trial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 164, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/hmrbcnt/Documents/thesis/try_2.1.5/trial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/topology.py", line 975, in from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/home/hmrbcnt/Documents/thesis/try_2.1.5/trial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/topology.py", line 961, in process_layer
    layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/hmrbcnt/Documents/thesis/try_2.1.5/trial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 63, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/hmrbcnt/Documents/thesis/try_2.1.5/trial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 166, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(config['config'])
  File "/home/hmrbcnt/Documents/thesis/try_2.1.5/trial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/topology.py", line 483, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "/home/hmrbcnt/Documents/thesis/try_2.1.5/trial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/topology.py", line 524, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Unrecognized keyword arguments:', kwargs.keys())
ValueError: ('Unrecognized keyword arguments:', dict_keys(['ragged']))
```

The reason why I use tensorflow.python.keras instead of tensorflow.keras is because using tensorflow.keras returns a ModuleNotFound error.
Version for tensorflow is 1.5, keras is 2.2.4. I can't use tensorflow version higher than 1.5 because I've got a pretty old CPU and it doesn't support avx instructions. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Changed errors and a line of code because I overlooked something and now get similar, but different error

Comment: Did you train this model using tf.keras? To me it seems that you are mixing tf.keras and keras, which are not compatible

Comment: I forgot to change a line of my code from keras.models to tf.keras.models, which I guess you were right about it not being compatible. But when I changed it, I get a new, yet similar error still about 'ragged'. And yes, I used tf.keras to train the model. Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to solve this?